# How to update toolstrip progress bar in MDI form from child?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using MDI and child forms. In MDI form, I placed the tool strip progress bar control to show the progress of some action in child forms. I am using the below code to run the progress bar. But it is not working. Please help me.

In MDI Form,

```
public void UpdateProgessBar(int currentCount, int targetCount, Color progressBarColor)
{
  toolStripProgressBar.ForeColor = progressBarColor;
  if (targetCount > 0 && currentCount > 0)
  {
    double progressBarValue = ((double)currentCount / targetCount) * 100;
    if (progressBarValue >= 0)
    {
      Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
      {
        toolStripProgressBar.Value = Convert.ToInt32(progressBarValue);
      });
  }
}
else
{
  Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
  {
    toolStripProgressBar.Value = 0;
  });
}
```

}

In Child Form,

```
MDIParent mdiParent = new MDIParent();
mdiParent.UpdateProgessBar(1, 1, Color.LimeGreen);
```

I am getting the error as

> "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.'"

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: `MDIParent mdiParent = new MDIParent();`  this references a "new" form that probably isn't on the screen.  A child MDI form has an `MdiParent` property.  Try using that (probably have to cast it).

Comment: Can you post a bit more code for context, such as who is calling this method and when is it called during the app's lifetime?  This error message (unlike some others) is actually telling you the problem: the window handle for the MDI Form (or whatever control this code lives in) has not been created.  Has the MDI form been shown yet?  Is this UpdateProgressBar function being called through the MDI form's constructor?  It should likely be triggered from the Load or FormShown event instead.  Even a call stack would be useful information.

Comment: After I changed this, var mdiParent = this.MdiParent as MDIParent; it started working.